# Where do field aliases reside in an SDE database?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql

If I want to get field aliases for an SDE table through pure SQL, what table do I query? My geodatabase was created with ArcGIS 10.1 in an Oracle database.

Comment: You have to parse metadata XML in GDB_* tables.